# function call and *expression

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a bit of confusion about parameters' rules in funcion header and arguments' rules in function calls.

Here is my confusing point:

According to the documentation:

> If the syntax *expression appears in the function call, expression must evaluate to an iterable. Elements from this iterable are treated as if they were additional positional arguments; if there are positional arguments x1, ..., xN, and expression evaluates to a sequence y1, ..., yM, this is equivalent to a call with M+N positional arguments x1, ..., xN, y1, ..., yM.

So if there is a function like this:

```
def func(a, *b): ....
```

why can't I do something like this:

```
func(1, *[2, 3], *[4, 5])
```

Isn't this equivalent to x1, ..., xN, y1, ..., yN, w1, ..., wN? 
Why doesn't this work?

Comment: And the very same documentation you quote includes the syntax grammar. The official grammar only allows for **one** `*expression`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, don't get confused by the fact that `*args` can be used both in function declarations and in function calls. Though the two are loosely related, they're not the same thing. You can call a function with `foo(*args)` without it being declared with a variable number of parameters and a function defined with `def foo(*args)` need not be called with an unpacked iterable.

The real issue you're seeing though is that only one `*args` unpacking is allowed in a function call. That's simply how Python's syntax has been specified. This may change in the future though, as [PEP 448](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) seeks generalize the unpacking syntax so it can be used in more situations. If the PEP gets approved and implemented, function calls like `foo(*args, *args2)` will become legal.

Answer (score 3):

First of al, it *doesn't matter what the function signature is*. The *call syntax* and the *function definition* are two separate concepts that happen to use `*` to mean related things. The definition of `f()` doesn't matter here.

It is the very grammar defined in the [*Calls* expressions documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls) that doesn't allow multiple `*expression*` parts:

> ```
> argument_list        ::=  positional_arguments ["," keyword_arguments]
>                             ["," "*" expression] ["," keyword_arguments]
>                             ["," "**" expression]
>                           | keyword_arguments ["," "*" expression]
>                             ["," keyword_arguments] ["," "**" expression]
>                           | "*" expression ["," keyword_arguments] ["," "**" expression]
>                           | "**" expression
> ```

Each `|` is an alternative part, each `[...]` is optional. None of these allow for `*expression` to appear more than once.

<strike>Note that there is a bug in the [Python 2 rendering of the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls), where</strike>

```
| "*" expression ["," keyword_arguments] ["," "**" expression]
```

has been replaced by the incorrect

```
| "*" expression ["," "*" expression] ["," "**" expression]
```

See [issue #22288](http://bugs.python.org/issue22288). (Documentation has [been fixed](http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/3ae399c6ecf6)).

Future Python versions **may** loosen this restriction. See [PEP 448 - *Additional Unpacking Generalizations*](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/); this would only apply to a future version of Python, Python 3.5 at the earliest.

Comment: Is there a reason why allow just one `*` and not more? I don't know, readability, usability...

Comment: @antox: simpler initial implementation, more likely. The PEP tries to focus discussion on what it can be expanded to. Guido seems to be positively inclined towards it (see his comments on a [related Python issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue2292)).

Answer (score 0):

Because the syntax doesn't allow it.

You can use the following instead to achieve the same effect:

```
func(1, *([2, 3] + [4, 5]))
```

Comment: The lazy iterator will be completely evaluated before the function gets called, so you don't gain anything.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You're right; I stand corrected (editing the answer).